# $\epsilon-N$ sequence convergence proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Prove that the sequence $\displaystyle{\frac{n^3+4}{3n^3-2n^2+1}}$ converges to $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{3}}$

Here's my (somewhat terse) proof. Can someone please verify it?

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Let $N = \displaystyle{\frac{13}{9\epsilon}+\frac{2}{3}}$, and let $n > N$.

Now, $\displaystyle{n > \frac{13}{9\epsilon} + \frac{2}{3}}$.

$\displaystyle{3n - 2 > \frac{13}{3\epsilon}}$

$\displaystyle{\frac{13}{3n-2}} < 3\epsilon$

$\displaystyle{\frac{13n^2}{3n^3-2n^2}}<3\epsilon$

$\displaystyle{\frac{13n^2}{3n^3-2n^2+1}} < 3\epsilon$

$\displaystyle{\frac{2n^2+11}{3n^3-2n^2+1} < 3\epsilon}$

$\displaystyle{\left|\frac{n^3+4}{3n^3-2n^2+1} - \frac{1}{3}\right| < \epsilon}$

Comment: Such as it is, your proof is correct bu difficult to read, since some steps are missing. First you should take $N$ as a integer large than $13/9\epsilon+2/3$ because this number is very likely not to be an integer (this is a minor remark). You should also add the intermediate inequalities you are using along the derivation to convince the reader. Last remark, this is somehow an artificial way to get the result, although it is correct, because it is written in the opposite direction as your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any flaw in your development.

You can take shortcuts, though:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^3+4}{3n^3-2n^2+1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1+\frac4{n^3}}{3-\frac2n+\frac1{n^3}}=\frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}1+\frac4{n^3}}{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}3-\frac2n+\frac1{n^3}}=\frac13$